# How to prevent animation reset when finished?

Tags: javascript, animation

I'm trying to animate the #Seleccioncollections by changing it's margin-top when is clicked.

Does the animation but when finished it returns to the starting point

this is the HTML:

```
<div id="Seleccioncollections">
        <div id="divimagencollectionbasic" class="imagencollections" ><img id="imagencollectionbasic"  src="/pagina/katana/img/aboutus/aboutusintro.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div id="divimagencollectionjdm" class="imagencollections" ><img id="imagencollectionjdm"  src="/pagina/katana/img/aboutus/aboutusintro.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div id="divimagencollectionsamurai" class="imagencollections" ><img id="imagencollectionsamurai"  src="/pagina/katana/img/aboutus/aboutusintro.jpg" alt=""></div>
    </div>
```

This is the scss:

```
#Seleccioncollections{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: space-around;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;

    .imagencollections{
        border: solid black 1px;
        width: 25%;

        img {
            width: 100%;
            height: 700px;
            object-fit: cover;
        }
    }
    
}
```

and this is the js:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".imagencollections").forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener("click", e => {
    const id = e.target.getAttribute("id");
    console.log("Se ha clickeado el id " + id);

    document.querySelector("#Seleccioncollections").animate({ marginTop: '0vh' }, 500);

    img = document.getElementById(id);

    const idpadre = img.parentNode.id

    console.log("el id del padre es " + idpadre);

    divimg = document.getElementById(idpadre);

    divimg.style.width = "100%";
    divimg.style.transition = "width 1s ease";

    const boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".imagencollections:not(#" + idpadre + ")");

    boxes.forEach(box => {

      box.style.display = "none";
    });


  });
});
```

Can someone please advise me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the issue with your animation is that when it finishes, the margin-top property is set back to its original value which causes the #Seleccioncollections element to return to its starting point.
To fix this, you can use a CSS animation instead of a JavaScript animation if that's an option for you:

SCSS:

```
#Seleccioncollections {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;

  .imagencollections {
    border: solid black 1px;
    width: 25%;

    img {
      width: 100%;
      height: 700px;
      object-fit: cover;
    }
  }

  &.animate {
    margin-top: 0vh;
    transition: margin-top 0.5s ease;
  }
}
```

JS:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".imagencollections").forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener("click", e => {
    const id = e.target.getAttribute("id");
    console.log("Se ha clickeado el id " + id);

    const idpadre = e.currentTarget.getAttribute("id");

    console.log("el id del padre es " + idpadre);

    const boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".imagencollections:not(#" + idpadre + ")");

    boxes.forEach(box => {
      box.style.display = "none";
    });

    const Seleccioncollections = document.querySelector("#Seleccioncollections");

    Seleccioncollections.classList.add("animate");
  });
});
```

The animation is now triggered by adding the animate class to the #Seleccioncollections element and wheen the animation finishes, the animate class is automatically removed, and now the margin-top property stays at its new value.